# Is there a Haskell equivalent way of iterable unpacking like in Python?

Tags: python, haskell, iterable-unpacking

I wonder if it is possible to create variables from an iterable of things in Haskell. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553370/how-do-i-unpack-a-list-as-individual-arguments-in-haskell) when I search for it but I couldn't adapt it for my case. Maybe it's not possible or I'm missing something since I'm a beginner. Basically, I'm wondering if something like this is possible in Haskell:

```py
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> a, b, c = list_of_lists
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You can unpack it, for example `let [a, b, c] = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] in a`. It is however nothing "special", like it is in Python, it is simple pattern matching. For most foldables (like `Tree`, `Maybe`, etc.), you can use `toList`.

Comment: It's called [pattern matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) and alongside lists, it works on many data types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ghci> list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
ghci> [a,b,c] = list_of_lists
ghci> print a
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by *luqui* works when the list has exactly three elements. It is, however, partial, which means that it'll fail at run-time for lists of any other size.

A more idiomatic Haskell solution, I think, would be a function like this:

```
listToTriple :: [a] -> Maybe (a, a, a)
listToTriple [a, b, c] = Just (a, b, c)
listToTriple _ = Nothing
```

You can safely call it with lists of any length:

```
*Q62157846> listToTriple [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Just ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
*Q62157846> listToTriple [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
Nothing
*Q62157846> listToTriple [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
Nothing
```

If, in the first case, you only want the first of those three lists, you can pattern-match on the triple:

```
*Q62157846> fmap (\(a, _, _) -> a) $ listToTriple [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Just [1,2,3]
```

Comment: I actually am sure that my list will have exactly 3 elements so it will not create any problem for this case. But I was also thinking that how would I proceed if the list has unknown size. So this definitely helps, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Asocia If you're sure that you have exactly three elements, a triple `(,,)` would be a better type to use than a list.

Comment: I'd strongly hesitate to recommend tuples here. Because they're in general heterogeneous, they offer much less convenient features than lists when used as homogeneous containers. In fact I tend to say tuples should _only_ be used when grouping together two elements of unknown, possibly different type. Honestly, a list is probably the most sensible solution. Sure, some type guarantee would be nice, but Haskell isn't a total language and often it's just not feasible. (Though it _should_ actually be doable nicely if the `IsString` class had an extra `Nat` parameter.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout One could define `data Triple a = Triple a a a`, then...

Comment: ...or use a library one, such as [`Linear.V3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear/docs/Linear-V3.html).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I didn't know about that library. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, I'm not creating my iterable manually. I'm using `groupBy` function, and I know I will have 3 groups at the end. So I just wanted to assign these groups to separate variables :)